# Python creating objects in a loop append items to same list instead of a new list

Tags: python, list, loops, object

I have a code that creates an object inside a loop. The object has a list that contains different type of object.

```
class A:
    a = ''
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    list_of_A = list()

for i in range(3):
    _b = B()
    for j in range(2):
        _a = A()
        _b.list_of_A.append(_a)
    print(len(_b.list_of_A))
```

The output is:
2
4
6

What I expected was:
2
2
2

I tried deleting `_b` at the end of the inner loop. But didn't work. 
How should I make sure the loop creates a new object of B.

Comment: Move `list_of_A = list()` into `__init__` and prepend `self.`, i.e. `def __init__(self): self.list_of_A = list()`. BTW, `list()` can be `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make `list_of_A` an instance variable, so it creates new list everytime you create an object:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_A = list()   # or = []
```

When you have the following arrangement:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    list_of_A = list()
```

`list_of_A` is shared by all objects of that class (because this is a class variable), and so you are appending to the same list object.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_A = list()
```

Reason: **Class Variable(or Static Variable) vs Instance Variable**

In your code, `list_of_A` is a class variable(or static variable) so it is same for all the objects(or instances) of class B.
In the code suggested above, `list_of_A` is an instance variable so it is different and unique for each object(or instance) of class B.